# Docker view the logs of failed / crashed container

Tags: docker, containers

I know you can check the logs of a running container with:

**Command to list containers**

`docker container ls`

**Command to view the logs**

`docker logs [container-id]`

**Question:**

Can you also check the logs of a failed container that is not listed, because the container failed?

Comment: Have you seen [How can I debug a docker container initialization?](https://serverfault.com/a/744711/992727)?

Answer (score 44):

**Answer:**

Command to list all containers, including failed / crashed containers:

`docker ps -a`

Now you will be able to find the id / name of your failed container and run the following command to check its logs:

`docker logs [container-id]`

Comment: I have a container that is crashing and it does not show up (after it crashes) in the list that I get from "docker ps -a".  Is there something else I need to do?  Are there logs anywhere that I can simply read without a docker command?

Comment: check for logs in /var/lib/docker/containers/

Comment: @Jer you could also try to start it without `-d` flag so the container can output to stdout when the error pops up during container startup.